# Magento 2 how to prevent to translate the shipping country region on multi-language website

Tags: php, magento2

After setting localization on Magento 2.1.9 backend, the shipping country combo box was translated so I can see the Russian country names.

But, I'd like to see them as English instead of Russian country names.

I can check the ru.xml, but there is no any updates.

```
 vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Locale\Data\ru.xml
```

How to prevent to translate the country list from English to Russian.

Is it possible?
http://prntscr.com/i4jeoh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
That part was created by AW_OneStepCheckout module.
Fortunately, there was configuration on backend setting.
But, when I changed the individual store, I could edit them.
Maybe that module's configuration had some issue.